# How did de Jussieu or Linnaeus practically manage the organization of plants?

Tags: biology, 18th-century, taxonomy

In 18th century botany, how did taxonomists such as Carl Linnaeus (Sweden) and Antoine-Laurent de Jussieu (France) manage to practically organize such a large number of plant species? For example, with an index card system, or something similar?

I'm interested generally in the practical side of plant classification in the 18th century, and Linnaeus and de Jussieu are specific and well-known examples. Encyclopedia entries and short biographies do not contain much information, but I'm sure it's related to the organization of plants in the Jardin du Roi or similar gardens, though I haven't been able to find much information on how these botanists actually managed their work.

(If the question is too broad, I would be interested in relevant references and sources for this sort of study.)

*Note: I'm not interested in how these systems themselves are organized (by reproductive organs, with artificial or natural selection of qualities) but instead I'm curious about the "bookkeeping" involved, how a person actually organizes their notes.*